# How to make a H2 DB with foreign key

Tags: mysql, h2, workbench

I need to make a H2 DB from this diagram made on Workbench. I'm having problem with foreign key. I'm learning MySQL.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Mbm.jpg)

The first table is working but the second syntax is not. Says that can't find turmas table.

```
create table Turmas (
"id_turmas" identity PRIMARY KEY,
"nome" varchar(50),
"periodo" VARCHAR(10) 
);

CREATE TABLE "Provas" (
    "id_provas" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "nome" VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    "data" VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    "Turmas_id_turmas" INT,

    CONSTRAINT "fk_Provas_Turmas1" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("Turmas_id_turmas") 
    REFERENCES "Turmas" ("id_turmas")
);
```

Comment: DB2 or MySQL? These are tow different DBMSs with different syntax. For example, DB2 uses doublequote symbols for object names quoting whereas MySQL do this only when ANSI_QUOTES SQL Mode is enabled (and it is disabled by default, in this case the values quoted are treated as string literals).

Comment: Please publish the full error message. Also why would you learn mysql to use h2 given they are different products and may not be fully compatible.